# How to programmatically mute video

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

How to play a video without sound?

I have tried these options but neither of them worked:

**1)** Setting the MPMusicPlayerController player to ipodMusicPlayer and disabling the application audio.

```
musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:0];
```

**2)** Forcing the app to run the audio

```
 NSError *error = nil;
 if ([[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error]) {
     NSLog(@"Error setting audio session: %@", error);
 }
```

Comment: Create a instances of musicPLayer and use that instances to mute the video, no need to use class method again. P.S some users have reported that its only works on a device and not on simulator

Comment: @ShamsAhmed I tried the method you suggested but this method is now depreciated and instead MpVolumeView is given which will need user interaction.

Comment: I hope that there is still some method that can disable the video's sound !!!

Answer (score 1):

Use this codebase to mute.

```
NSError *errorFeedBack = nil;

if (![[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:&errorFeedBack] ) 
{
    NSLog(@"Error encountered: %@", [errorFeedBack localizedDescription]);
}
```